# If a cube magnet were a die, how would it be numbered?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, magnetic-fields

I have a number of cube-shaped magnets. If I start with 64 cubes all in one long chain and begin arbitrarily "folding over" groups of them so that I am left with a 4x4x4 cube, I rarely get the same behaviour attempting move some. (Sometimes an entire sheet of 16 moves as a group, sometimes one row stays behind, and sometimes only one row really wants to move. Additionally, when splitting any arbitrary 2x4 grouping, there is always a favored "pivot", eg, some cubes seem more strongly stuck to cubes "next" to them, eg there are a variety of strengths between one magnet's non-pole face to another magnet's non-pole face.)

This leads me to wonder what is going on here, and how to find out, and so I thought that since I was going to label their poles, might as well label them as dice with North as 1 and South as 6. As I began to add the rest I wondered if the non-pole faces are identical for all intents and purposes, and figured that someone must have gone down this road before.

**Is there a standard for numbering the six faces of each magnet from 1-6 such that each number indicates the expected magnetic characteristics (polarity, etc.) of each face, while respecting the standard numbering for dice (opposing pairs sum to 7, etc.).**

If no such standard exists, what shall it be, and why?

Comment: there's nothing fundamentally cube-shaped about a magnetic field, why would this be useful to anyone? (for a start, why is it useful to you?)

Comment: I suppose the real question is "are the four non-polar faces of a cube-shaped magnet exhibit identical magnetic characteristics?". I am labeling my cube magnets like dice and I would rather not conflict with any other.

Comment: maybe you should edit your question

Comment: in general it's impossible to know how you should do this without knowing what kind of field the die have, they could be roughly dipoles, or quadrupoles, or some higher number of poles.

Comment: I strongly suspect that there is no standard labeling system because there is no great need for one.

Comment: They are dipoles. Are all the non-pole sides the same in terms of magnetic field?

Comment: I love the thought of this game. Sounds like a great science demonstration at a primary / early secondary school.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to establish a standard to number a die.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a fun game and seems to me to be a highly evocative analogy for microscopic domain behaviour.

Ideally, there should be a north pole face, a south pole face and the other four faces are *all magnetically equivalent* to one another. That is, the cube's magnetic behavior is invariant with respect to 90, 180, 270, ... degree rotations about an axis linking the centers of the north and south pole faces.  So ideally one doesn't need to number these other faces: the behavior is uniquely defined by marking the north and south faces.

The magnetic source can be thought of as a dipole, and then the field lines are influenced by the magnetic constants (I should say magnetic functions, because they are highly nonlinear) of the ferromagnetic material and the air outside. The ideal behavior I just talked about will arise if the magnets are "perfect": *i.e.* the dipole lies perfectly along the line joining the centers of north and south pole faces.

Practically, the dipole placement won't be perfect. So there will be a unique (or near to) way of arranging all the faces that minimises the total system energy, but there will be many near-to-minimum configurations (which would be equal minimum with the perfect behavior described above): owing the the mechanical constraints, there are very definite local mimimums in system energy and many unstable equilibriums at local maximum energy confgurations. That's why you see the "whimsy, dithering" behavior, where whole rows suddenly seem "unsure" of which way to go and snap into position: you're pushing them over a local maximum in system energy, which makes an unstable equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks! Verifying my understanding: The magnetic pole rarely ever *exactly* passes through the precise middles of any two opposing faces, and as such the plane containing the four points on at the respective precise middle of each nonpolar face of the cube is intersected by the magnetic pole at an angle rarely exactly 90 degrees and rarely ever identical to that of any other similar cube? If that is correct, why the imperfection, is it quantifiable, and how is such variance rated (eg, how do I find magnetically perfect cubes?)

Answer (score 0):

First the answer to your question:
If the cube magnet acts like a dipole, I think a simple dot on the north would suffice. I think it would be quite easy to manufacture them with a dot Since it's only a matter of changing the mold. Quote: "The magnets are made by sintering, a method of welding tiny particles of metal together by the application of heat. Any ‘holes’ present in a rare-earth magnet have not been drilled. The sintered mixture of metal was poured into a mold at the time of the magnet’s manufacture".

[Source](http://strong-rare-earth-magnets.com/can-neodymium-magnets-be-drilled-and-machined/)

Now as a response to the comment: 'Why would this be useful'. Consider you have a flat disk magnet with a certain surface which creates a certain force on whiteboard. I want to combine several small cube magnets to create a flat surface magnet which creates a similar magneting force as the disk magnet, it's very hard if you don't know the polarity of the magnet... (Or similar, what's the best configuration to put 8 $5*5*5$ cubes into a $10*10*10$ cube or any other $a*b*c$ block magnet for your specific application).

Hope this was useful to anyone, made an account specially to answer this question and hope that perhaps in future I'll be able to buy dotted cube magnets :).